# Is it possible to disable data binding for a control until it has the correct DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, prism, prism-6

I have a selection view with a list of `DetailViewModel` objects. When one of these is selected, it is passed to a detail view (derived from `UserControl`) using Prism view switching navigation. Because the detail view is loaded when the module is loaded, it tries to bind to the ambient data context before it is ever navigated to.

That is, when the module is loaded, the detail view is loaded in a region in `MainWindowView`, and tries to bind to the `MainWindowViewModel` before its real viewmodel is set during navigation. I would like to prevent this first, erroneous binding, and only bind when the detail view has been assigned it's proper viewmodel. Is this possible, and how?

Failing that, could I maybe only register the view with the region after the module has initialized, only when I need to navigate to that detail view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technique that may work for you, and one that is typical in Prism, is *view injection*. You can find more about it [here](http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/08-Navigation/#view-based-navigation). This is different than *view discovery*, which is where you register everything up front during module loading.

The premise of view injection is that you assign a view to a region via code based on something happening. So, rather than using `RegisterViewWithRegion` during module initialization, you do something like the following in your controller, or where ever.

```
//IRegionManager regionManager = <get this via ctor injection, or resolve this from the contain>;
IRegion contentRegion = regionManager.Regions["ContentRegion"];
InterestingView view = this.container.Resolve<InterestingView>();
// Set view.DataContext here, maybe...
// either via the container, or newing something up
mainRegion.Add(view);
mainRegion.Activate(view); // shows the view
```

I have not tried it, but I don’t see a reason why you couldn’t set the `DataContext` on the view before adding it to the region. But, if you use the `ViewModelLocator` that comes with Prism, you may not have to worry about it.

You can find a full example of view injection on the Prism GitHub [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/695a7ef7152978156c1e251cd20343574e411939/UIComposition/UIComposition.EmployeeModule/Controllers/MainRegionController.cs).

You may know that modules in Prism are optional. But, they do provide a mechanism that lets you do all this binding right up front. *But*, I can understand the need for a little more control at times.

Comment: This is exactly along the lines of what I've been thinking since first posting my question. I would also rather not have my detail region stuffed full of unused views, even with on demand module loading, there is still no unloading. I just couldn't quite figure how to do it yet.

Comment: I'm not using the `ViewModelLocator` because I already have the viewmodel in the selection view, and pass it to the detail view as a navigation parameter. The locator works too nicely for other viewmodels though.

Comment: I hope you find it useful. I can see this being a really good option, especially for larger applications when the number of modules/views really starts to grow.